# Recoll: trouble finding content, finds less if search string is shorter

Tags: full-text-search, recoll

But I have troubles finding content in text files:
Platform: Linux

It has indexed a large directory tree with many *.txt files

If I ask it for: "ext:txt  N57D30O0"

I get 41 results.

If I ask it for: "ext:txt  N57D30"
I get only 8 results, I would expect more or same results.

I just cannot understand why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use an asterisk wildcard: N57S30*

Recoll matches words, not parts of words, except if you use wildcards.